# How to keep repeating a program until a range of numbers is entered eg 1-99

Tags: python

Cant seem to understand why it wont except a range but it will except a blank space inbetween the '' im new to coding

```
User_age = (input('Please enter your age '))
while True:             
    inp = input()   
    if inp == range(1,99):
        break      
    else:
      print("please input a valid age")
```

Comment: First of all, `input` returns a string. If you want a number, you'd need to convert it to integer with `int()`. Second, if you want to check if a number is within range, you need to use `in` keyword, not equality (`==`), as a number is NOT equal to a range.

Comment: you have not converted inp into `int` hence always else condition runs.

Comment: thank you really appreciated, trying some coding challenges for revision and needed to go a bit harder

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `if inp == range(1,99)` you can use `if inp in range(1,99)` to make it more sense to validate that your input is in range 1 to 99. Don't forget to change the input type to int to avoid errors because `range(1,99)` returns integers with ranges 1 to 99.

```py
while True:             
    inp = int(input('Please enter your age: '))   
    if inp in range(1,99):
        break      
    else:
      print("please input a valid age")
```

Comment: Conversion to `list` is not necessary, and actually a bad idea since it will lead to less efficient execution (more computation time, more memory required). Also, beware of `99` being outside of the range.

Answer (score 0):

This code also checks that if user input the ***number*** than only convert into integer else not. The code will not produce **compilation error** *{ValueError}* when someone write other than number.

**Code:**

```
while True:
    age=input('Please enter your age: ')
    if age.isnumeric() and int(age) in range(1,100):
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid age between 1 and 99.")

print("Age: ",age)
```

**Output:**

```
Please enter your age: -1
Please enter a valid age between 1 and 99.
Please enter your age: eighteen
Please enter a valid age between 1 and 99.
Please enter your age: 101
Please enter a valid age between 1 and 99.
Please enter your age: 34
Age:  34
```